# How do I solve a non-linear equation in Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy, solver, equation-solving

How do I solve a non-linear equation in SymPy which is of the form

```
y = P*x + Q + sqrt(S*x + T)
```

where I know `y(0)`, `y'(0)`, `y(c)`, `y'(c)`. I want to find `P`, `Q`, `S` and `T`. and represent `y` as a function of `x`.

I am getting very confused with the documentation. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

NOTE: My sympy hanged on your original equation of `y = P*x + Q + sqrt(S*x + T)`. 
I will be using `y = P*x + Q + x*x*(S*x + T)` just to be able to demonstrate how the sympy solver works (when it works).

**Strategy:**

- Express y as a function of the other variables (x, P, Q, S, T)
- Differentiate y
- Set up 4 equations using the known constants ( 0, c, y(0), y(c), y'(0), y'(c) )
- Use sympy solve
- Print each possible solution (if there are any)

**Code:**

```
# Set up variables and equations
x, y, P, Q, S, T,  = sympy.symbols('x y P Q S T')
c, y_0, y_c, dy_0, dy_c = sympy.symbols('c y_0 y_c dy_0 dy_c')
eq_y = P * x + Q + x * x * (S * x + T)
eq_dy = eq_y.diff(x)

# Set up simultaneous equations that sympy will solve
equations = [
    (y_0 - eq_y).subs(x, 0),
    (dy_0 - eq_dy).subs(x, 0),
    (y_c - eq_y).subs(x, c),
    (dy_c - eq_dy).subs(x, c)
]

# Solve it for P, Q, S and T
solution_set = sympy.solve(equations, P, Q, S, T, set = True) 

# Extract names, individual solutions and print everything
names = solution_set[0]
solutions = list(solution_set[1])
for k in range(len(solutions)):
    print('Solution #%d' % (k+1))
    for k2, name in enumerate(names):
        print('\t%s: %s' % (name, solutions[k][k2]) )
```

**Output:**

```
Solution #1
    P: dy_0
    Q: y_0
    S: (c*(dy_0 + dy_c) + 2*y_0 - 2*y_c)/c**3
    T: (-c*(2*dy_0 + dy_c) - 3*y_0 + 3*y_c)/c**2
```

You can now use one of these solutions and do another `.subs(...)` to get `y` as a function purely consisting of your constants and `x`.

As for your original equation... I wonder if someone should file a bug report for sympy so they can improve upon it... :)

Answer (score 1):

Right now solver have some issue in solving system of equation having more `sqrt`. So in below code first removing the `sqrt` and then solving system of equation.Currently solver is not fast for these types of equations ,it is taking around 10 sec to execute.

```
P, Q, S, T,  = symbols('P Q S T')
c, y_0, y_c, dy_0, dy_c = symbols('c y_0 y_c dy_0 dy_c')
eq_y = (P*x + Q - y(x))**2 + S*x + T
eq_dy = eq_y.diff(x)
equations = [
  (eq_y).subs([(x, 0), (y(0), y_0), (y(x).diff(x).subs(x, 0), dy_0)]),
  (eq_dy).subs([(x, 0), (y(0), y_0), (y(x).diff(x).subs(x, 0), dy_0)]),
  (eq_y).subs([(x, c), (y(c), y_c), (y(x).diff(x).subs(x, c), dy_c)]),
  (eq_dy).subs([(x, c), (y(c), y_c), (y(x).diff(x).subs(x, c), dy_c)])
 ]
solve(equations, P, Q, S, T)
```

Answer :

```
  [(-(y_0 - y_c)/c, y_0, 0, 0), ((2*c*dy_0*dy_c + dy_0*y_0 - dy_0*y_c + dy_c*y_0 - dy_c*y_c)/(c*dy_0 + c*dy_c + 2*y_0 - 2*y_c), -(2*c**3*dy_0*dy_c**2 - c**2*dy_0**2*y_0 + 2*c**2*dy_0*dy_c*y_0 - 4*c**2*dy_0*dy_c*y_c + c**2*dy_c**2*y_0 - 2*c**2*dy_c**2*y_c - 2*c*dy_0*y_0**2 + 2*c*dy_0*y_c**2 - 4*c*dy_c*y_0*y_c + 4*c*dy_c*y_c**2 - 2*y_0**3 + 2*y_0**2*y_c + 2*y_0*y_c**2 - 2*y_c**3)/(c*dy_0 + c*dy_c + 2*y_0 - 2*y_c)**2, -4*(dy_0 - dy_c)*(c*dy_0 + y_0 - y_c)**2*(c*dy_c + y_0 - y_c)**2/(c*dy_0 + c*dy_c + 2*y_0 - 2*y_c)**3, -4*(c*dy_0 + y_0 - y_c)**2*(c*dy_c + y_0 - y_c)**4/(c*dy_0 + c*dy_c + 2*y_0 - 2*y_c)**4)]
```

please cross check the answer.